# Windows Phone update binding from background thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

In my Windows Phone 8 Application I have Listbox below

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1"  ItemsSource="{Binding}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Grid>
<TextBlock  Text="{Binding snippet.DownloadPercentage}" 
TextWrapping="Wrap"
FontFamily="Portable User Interface"/>
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I am downloading file asyn and would like to give progress percentage to UI like below;
but it does not update UI. It shows always 0 which is initial int value. If I access DownloadPercentage property at main thread
the it updates with no problem.

```
 private void ClientOnDownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs downloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
        {
            // not working
            item.snippet.DownloadPercentage = progressPercentage;

            // not working      
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate {
               item.snippet.DownloadPercentage = progressPercentage;

            });    
            // not working
            ProgressChangedEventHandler workerProgressChanged = delegate {
                item.snippet.DownloadPercentage = progressPercentage;
            };
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.ProgressChanged += workerProgressChanged;
            worker.ReportProgress(progressPercentage);

            // WORKING!
            #region ProgressIndicator
            _progressIndicator.Text = string.Format("Downloading ({0}%) {1}", progressPercentage, item.snippet.Title);
            _progressIndicator.IsVisible = true;
            _progressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = true;
            SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, _progressIndicator);
            #endregion

        }
```

what can I do?

Solution;
after @DecadeMoon's hint I had to implement INotifyPropertyChanged over Snippet class.

```
public class Snippet : INotifyPropertyChanged
    { 
 [JsonProperty("downloadPercentage")]
        public int DownloadPercentage
        {
            get { return _downloadPercentage; }
            set
            {
                _downloadPercentage = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("DownloadPercentage");
            }
        }
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does your snippet class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: It does not implement, however if I access same property at main thread, like on page load it updates binding and changes UI. Does it make difference for background thread?

Comment: Are you saying that if you set `item.snippet.DownloadPercentage` on page load on UI thread, that it updates the textbox text? I don't believe you :)

Comment: What about just `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => item.snippet.DownloadPercentage = progressPercentage;)`?

Comment: The UI is not going to update the binding value unless your snippet class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and you raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the `DownloadPercentage` property.

Comment: @DecadeMoon item.snippet is my model class, I believe it does not need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, if you are asking my view -model it does implement INotifyPropertyChanged :)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I tried it as well, no luck..

Comment: @Teoman You're binding to a property on the snippet class, therefore the snippet class *must* implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, or else how can the view know when the `DownloadPercentage` property has changed?

Comment: @DecadeMoon You are absolutely right! Working great know :) If you wish change your comment as an answer then I can mark it. I was a little confused about INotifyPropertyChanged concept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object whose property you have bound to in the view must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. In your case, you're binding to `snippet.DownloadPercentage`, therefore the snippet class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and must raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the `DownloadPercentage` property.

You must also make sure that you only modify the `DownloadPercentage` property from the UI thread, otherwise you'll get an exception if modified from another thread. This is generally done by using the dispatcher:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    item.snippet.DownloadPercentage = progressPercentage;
});
```